# Requirements for including Boost source code in your own library

Tags: licensing

According to the Boost license, if I include any of the source code in the Boost library in my own, I have to include a copy of their license alongside my library (https://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt).

Does "including" the license mean I simply have to include a single file of the license alongisde my ENTIRE library, stating that I used SOME Boost code with my library, or would I need to include the license above, for example, with every function or file where I used Boost code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you copy files or functions with a Boost license into your own project, there are a number of things you must do

1. Each copied function or file must have a comment with the original copyright notice and a statement which license applies. If you copied an entire file, those things should already be present. If you create an entire file with only functions under the Boost license, this comment can be placed once in the file.
2. At least one copy of the entire text of the license must be present in your repository in a place where it can be easily found by people interested in knowing the license terms that apply to each part of your library.